# Calculating number of thumbs based off resolution

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, resolution

I have a thumbnail gallery and I want to only display "X" number of images where "X" fits perfectly into the specific users browser window based off their resolution.

The reason why this is important is because if I do not calculate this based off their resolution, and pull a static number of images, on some resolutions there will be an uneven number on the bottom row. This looks pretty ugly.

Is there a way to calculate the correct number of images to display based off resolution (I can get the resolution via window.height and window.width if necessary - the thumbs are pulled dynamically so this isn't a problem)?

The way I'm currently doing it is using a huge switch statement with the various resolutions and hardcoded 'number of image' values, and the page loads sends the resolution to the PHP script which passes it into this switch statement, however this is impractical and seems to have unpredictable behavior on different monitors, even monitors with the same resolution. Surely there is a way to calculate this dynamically? Or at least a better solution to the seemingly terrible one I'm currently using.

Thanks.

Comment: `thumbs_per_row = floor(width / (thumbnail_width + left_padding + right_padding)); thumbs = thumbs_per_row * rows`. What problem are you having exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an algebra question.  Given width x height ... but we know that the thumbnails won't squish into irregular sizes.  So we calculate how many will fit within our width (given the css margins between them).  Do the same for height.  I can't code it for you because I don't have the width and height of each thumbnail, but I also see it'd be very straight-forward.

Comment: I'm using percentages for the margins, is that going to be a problem? I tried to do that earlier but it seemed to be way off... Maybe one of my calculations were wrong haha.

Comment: Maybe.  Get me some numbers on image size (w/h) and the cell distance you'd like between them, and we can push a calculator around.  By "margin", do you mean left and right of the thumbs or do you mean between them or both?

Comment: Another option is intentionally load a row or two too many, show a "fade to white" over top of this last row, and it gives the hint that the user can scroll to see more.  As they scroll, show a spinner in the last spot, and load another page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more powerful version of jQuery's `.filter()` function by passing it, well, a filter function. :p

```
$(selector).filter(function () { });
```

This iterates through each element in your jQuery object, and runs the filter function against it. If the function returns a `truthy` value, the element is retained; `falsy` discards.

So for your use case, let's assume that all your gallery images are somehow cached in a jQuery object:

```
// gallery images
var _images = $('img');
```

You can then get only those images that fit some width by running a filter function on it like:

```
var _fits = _images.filter(function () {

    // as the filter function iterates, 
    // [this] is the current element.

    return (this.width === window.width);
});
```

Hope that helps.

#### EDIT

On rereading your question, it seems that I've misunderstood.

If you have a set of images, and want to make it fit perfectly into some set width, it's entirely possible to have more than one possible combination where a subset of images fits, and it's also entirely possible that no subset fits perfectly.

One (sort of) easy workaround is to just use a layouting plugin to do the heavy algorithmic work for you. One that comes to mind is [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (check out the **fitRows** layout mode) and it's free to use for non-commercial / personal use.